# NSString weakly holding const char * of std::string

Tags: c++, cocoa, nsstring, objective-c++, stdstring

What's the safest way for a NSString to weakly contain a const char * belonging to a std::string?  Both examples below work on a simple test, in logs, and as presented in a NSTableView, but I'm concerned about strange behavior down to road. It may be the extra null character of c_str() is simply ignored (because of the length parameter passed) and either will work fine.

Given:

```
std::string const * stdstring = new std::string("Let's see if this works");
```

Then:

```
NSString * aStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytesNoCopy: 
    stdstring->data() length: stdstring->length() 
    encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding  freeWhenDone:NO];
```

or:

```
NSString * aStr2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytesNoCopy: 
    stdstring->c_str() length: stdstring->length() 
     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding  freeWhenDone:NO];
```

or something else?

Comment: To others reading this, string copying is ridiculously cheap in the vast majority of cases; unless your parsing huge (100kB+) strings, do not risk this.  If you are doing that, do confirm your need to load them as a single string first; and profile before looking at 'speed-ups' like this.

Comment: Be aware that you are having `NSString` weakly hold a `char *` that belongs to a `std::string`, not a `const char *`. What you described does not work for a `const char *`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for `initWithBytesNoCopy:length:...` clearly states that the `length` will be the number of bytes used, so the null termination character will always be ignored. Hence the contents of the memory returned by `data()` and `c_str()` is equally suitable.

With that in mind:

The lifetime guarantees of the memory returned by `std::string`'s `data()` and `c_str()` functions are identical - they will survive until you call a non-const member function on the string object. It depends on the implementation whether the internal data structure is already a null-terminated character array, so in general, `data()` will be cheaper or identical in complexity to `c_str()`. I'd therefore go for `data()`.

Comment: Note also that with the upcoming standard c_str() and data() will become synonyms per the standard specification